# Laravel 5.5 returning unique values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I create system messages and I have problem in one moment, when i have user who send messages and user who gets messages. How to return one message no matter who sent and who received and how many of these messages were? I want create list messages. I want to create a list of messages where the last message is displayed in the list, when clicked on it will be the whole conversation

```
  public function mymessages()
{

    $user= Auth::user()->id;
    $messages = Messages::latest()->where('id_user_to_send',$user)->orWhere('id_user_from',$user)->get();
    return $messages;
    return view('messages.inbox', compact('messages'));
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_user_to_send')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_user_from')->unsigned();
        $table->string('text');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->foreign('id_user_to_send')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('id_user_from')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `first()` you get one result:

```
Messages::where('id_user_to_send',$user)
        ->orWhere('id_user_from',$user)
        ->orderBY('id', 'DESC')
        ->groupBY('id_conversation')
        ->first();
```

Comment: Yes, but i won't one result for conversation. 
It's about grouping messages.